# Can the Visual Studio Data Compare tools synchronize filetable data

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014-express

I have the need to sync schema and data between databases.  I've used the Visual Studio SQL Server Compare tools to do this for many years. Recently i've started to play with Filetable tables, and need to sync these.  The Schema compare is able to sync the schema correctly, including the Filetable, but the Data compare doesn't attempt to sync the file table data.

Visual Studio Community 2015 v14.0.25123.00 Update 2

Is this functionality just lacking, or am I doing it wrong?